# iconv fails with undefined symbol: __gconv_open

Tags: linux, glibc

An error occurs when I run `iconv` even if it's called without arguments.
Is my OS somehow corrupt or broken or is some installation wrong?

What I tried so far:

- looking up environment variables: `env` <- does not seem wrong or corrupted
- running `iconvconfig`
- updating/reinstalling `libtext-iconv-perl` and `node-iconv-lite`:

  - `sudo apt reinstall libtext-iconv-perl node-iconv-lite`
- updating/reinstalling libc-bin:

  - `sudo apt install libc-bin`
  - `sudo apt reinstall libc-bin`
- running `iconvconfig` again
- running iconv with empty `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, because it's full of ROS-foxy dependencies:

  - `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= /usr/bin/iconv`
  - `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" /usr/bin/iconv`

I discovered that a definition of `__gconv_open` exists in this repository: https://github.com/lattera/glibc so I cloned it to my home directory and searched for some of the defines and compared them to the installation on my OS but I couldn't really find anything useful. There is only one header in `/usr/include/gconv.h` but it doesn't even declare `__gconv_open` and at this point I am lost. Does anybody has an idea?

Full error message:

> iconv: symbol lookup error: iconv: undefined symbol: __gconv_open, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

My System, output of `uname -a`:

> Linux kama-100 5.15.0-71-generic #78~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 19 11:26:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux